# Tezos vs Decred

Tags: altcoin, currencies, altcoin-development, governance

What are the main differences  between [Decred](https://www.decred.org/) and [Tezos](https://www.tezos.com/)  ?

Both integrate a governance mechanism so they don't seem very different to me.

Answer (score 3):

Decred is limited in what you can amend with on-chain governance. With Tezos you can amend any part of the protocol, including the governance mechanism itself.

Answer (score 1):

Both have a value proposition of onchain decentralized governance. Decred has a live working blockchain and the on-chain voting feature while Tezos is still a concept.